# Pyspark in Docker based on Hortonworks 2.6.1 is throwing error with EnableHiveSupport()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to build an edge-node using docker with HDP2.6.1. Everything is available and running except Spark Support. I was able to install and run pyspark  but only when I comment enableHiveSupport(). I have copied over the hive-site.xml to /etc/spark2/conf as well from ambari and all the spark confs are matching with the cluster settings. But still get this error:

```
17/10/27 02:35:57 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.groupby.position.alias does not exist
17/10/27 02:35:57 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.mv.files.thread does not exist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 43, in <module>
    spark = SparkSession.builder\
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 187, in getOrCreate
    session._jsparkSession.sessionState().conf().setConfString(key, value)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 79, in deco
    raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u"Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':"
>>> spark.createDataFrame([(1,'a'), (2,'b')], ['id', 'nm'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'spark' is not defined
```

I have tried to search this error, but all the results that I get are possible windows errors related to permissions and hive-site.xml missing. But i am building it on centos:7.3.1611. And installing the following:

```
RUN wget http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos7/2.x/updates/2.6.1.0/hdp.repo
RUN cp hdp.repo /etc/yum.repos.d
RUN yum -y install hadoop sqoop spark2_2_6_1_0_129-master spark2_2_6_1_0_129-python hive-hcatalog
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution to the above problem is that the hive-site.xml needs to only contain the property for hive.metastore.uris and NOTHING ELSE. (Reference: https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.2/bk_spark-component-guide/content/spark-config-hive.html). Once you take the other properties out, it works like a charm!